# Dependent dropdown menu using ajax not refreshing but console is showing data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a MVC structure and here is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select[name="provider_id"]').change(function() {
        var provider_id = $(this).val();

        if (provider_id) {

            $.ajax({
                    url: url + '/ProductsAjax/GetOutletByProvider',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        provider_id: provider_id
                    },
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        var outlets = "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.outlet_name + "</option>";
                        $('select[name="outlet"]').append(outlets);
                        console.log(item.id + ' ' + item.outlet_name);
                    })

                })

                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                    console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
                });

        } else {

            $('select[name="outlet"]').empty();
        }
    });
</script>
```

It is outputting the correct data in console but the dropdown menu itself does not show the data at all. Nothing happens.

Here are the select menus:

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
        <label for="example_input_full_name">
            Select Service Provider
        </label>
        <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" name="provider_id">
            <option value="">Select Service Provider</option>
            <?php foreach($data['sproviders'] as $service_provider): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $service_provider->service_provider_id; ?>"><?php echo $service_provider->sp_name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
       <label for="example_input_full_name">
           Select Outlet
       </label>
        <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" name="outlet" id="outlet">
        </select>
</div>
```

Since the correct data is displaying in console, I can't figure out why it isn't pulling through into the second select menu.

Console data:

```
108 Branch One
109 Branch Two
110 Branch Three
```

Comment: What result you are getting in console.log(data) after .done(function(data) { ?

Comment: @Nirali, console is showing me the id and name of as many records there are in the database i.e.: the data I am expecting

Comment: Can you show the data format? Because your script working for me my dummy dataset. So, there must be something wrong with format result

Comment: Sorry, how do I go about showing the data format?

Comment: sample result of data.which your seeing in console

Comment: 107 Branch One
108 Branch Two
109 Branch Three

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169742/discussion-between-nirali-and-user8463989).

Comment: show us output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, how do I copy and paste the console output to show you? Each database record is showing one below the other

Comment: only show 2-3 records. add in your question

Comment: Done. Hope that is what you meant

Comment: Does selectpicker not need a refresh perhaps? Not sure if it does and how to do it (quick google in progress)

Comment: Would you `console.log(outlets);` please ?

Comment: Hmm. Yes, that is the case. `$('select[name="outlet"]').selectpicker('refresh');` but this just keeps adding to the dropdown instead of removing content and adding the new content for a new selection

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select[name="provider_id"]').change(function() {
        var provider_id = $(this).val();

        if (provider_id) {

            $.ajax({
                    url: url + '/ProductsAjax/GetOutletByProvider',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        provider_id: provider_id
                    },
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    var outlets="";
                    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                        outlets += "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.outlet_name + "</option>";  // concat all options                      
                        console.log(item.id + ' ' + item.outlet_name);
                    })
                    $('select[name="outlet"]').html(outlets); // add all options

                })

                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                    console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
                });

        } else {

            $('select[name="outlet"]').empty();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, unfortunately the result is the same with your code

Comment: try by replacing  `$('select[name="outlet"]').html(outlets);` this line with `$("#outlet").html(outlets);` this

Comment: Still the same unfortunatley